# Why does the "new" > "recommended" tab give always 96 questions?

Tags: discussion, support, status-norepro, new-nav, recommended-tab

["New" > "recommended" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=new&tagFilter=recommended) constantly shows 96 questions for me.

> [image]

Why is that? Why exactly 96, not 100, or some round number?

Comment: Note that you must switch to "Show excerpts", as shown in the screen grab - picking "Hide excerpts", which seems to be the default (??), doesn't show the question count.

Comment: Why should it be some round number? Why not 42?

Comment: @idmean because they represent 96 tears.

Comment: Answered at [the cross-site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261337/159034). It's for historical front page reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The count on the homepage has been removed in the current release.

Comment: Lol, but there're still 96 questions, even without the counter :D The cross site dupe answers my question though.