# Home tab missing question count and expand/collapse controls in new nav

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

The home tab does not display the question count and the expand/collapse controls.  This makes it very inconvenient to toggle between expanded and collapsed question previews.  I have to switch to a different tab, change the setting there, and then go back to the home tab.

> [image: Home tab missing controls]

It's present on other tabs

> [image: Other tabs have controls]

Comment: According to [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309028/2607247) the question count missing is by-design. The controls disappearing is probably an accidental side effect of removing the count.

Comment: That's really unfortunate.  I guess there's still a lot of polishing to be done.