# Right nav missing

Tags: bug, new-nav, sidebar

In my Safari (9.0.3, vanilla config as far as I know, on OSX 10.11.3), **using the [new SO nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing)** if I view the Questions tab, navigate to to a question, my righthand nav disappears entirely.  Similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309033/home-tab-missing-question-count-and-expand-collapse-controls-in-new-nav), but worse.  Works fine on Chrome.

Start at Questions...

[image]

Select a question, then browser back-button...

[image]

Am I misunderstanding something, or is there a known bug?

Note that sidebar element is empty in this case (good idea by @Alexander O'Mara to inspect this)...

[image]

Comment: Adblocker? Or something?

Comment: Zoomed in / out? Could the sidebar be hiding at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Not zoomed.  No ad blocker that I know about.  @Oded - what would it look like hiding at bottom?  The bottoms look normal, and the same before and after.  BTW, not a debilitating problem.  I work-around with a reload.

Comment: Huh? It disappears and a refresh makes it show up - is that right? Do you have any user scripts installed?

Comment: Yes.  To be clear, "reload" meaning request the page again.  My browser is configured (as far as I know) like a fresh Safari install.

Comment: New behavior with new nav, I think.  Would test old nav, but I don't know how to return to it.

Comment: To get back to old behaviour - to to your preferences page and uncheck "I would like to participate in testing the new navigation.". What version of Safari and on what OS version?

Comment: Safari 9.0.3, OSX 10.11.3.  Waiting for old nav preference to take effect.  Will retest when that happens.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Safari 9.0.3 (10601.4.4), OS X 10.10.5. It disappears after I go back to the questions list. Possible hint from developer console: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.innerHTML')` (I only saw that error the first time though.)

Comment: Another hint: The `<div id="sidebar"></div>` element become completely empty when this happens. It not a drawing issue, something is blanking it out (possibly by assigning innerHTML to empty string).

Comment: Just confirmed this occurs only with new nav.  Old nav works as expected.